# Agora RTC - Unity Build Crash

Tags: unity-game-engine, crash-reports, agora.io

I have integrated agora sdk in my unity project. It was working fine till last week but now unity windows build crashes after some time. I am attaching stack trace which i get from unity crash report, to help you with logs. Unable to find any solution yet

```
Native StackTrace:

Thread 0
0   ntdll                              0x00007ffc41e30ab4 NtWaitForAlertByThreadId 
1   ntdll                              0x00007ffc41db9205 RtlAcquireSRWLockExclusive 
2   agora_rtc_sdk                      0x00007ffb749b2335 <symbols missing for uuid: 0BD580850DF84A4D9F72BBCF64F22C931> 
3   agora_rtc_sdk                      0x00007ffb744bbd05 <symbols missing for uuid: 0BD580850DF84A4D9F72BBCF64F22C931> 
4   KERNELBASE                         0x00007ffc3f9e0207 UnhandledExceptionFilter 
5   ntdll                              0x00007ffc41e35530 RtlUserThreadStart$filt$0 
6   ntdll                              0x00007ffc41e1c876 _C_specific_handler 
7   ntdll                              0x00007ffc41e3241f RtlpExecuteHandlerForException 
8   ntdll                              0x00007ffc41de14a4 RtlDispatchException 
9   ntdll                              0x00007ffc41e30f4e KiUserExceptionDispatcher 
10  UnityPlayer                        0x00007ffb7ca44bc1 WindowsVideoTextureOutput::ReleaseDrawnSamples (C:\build\output\unity\unity\Modules\Video\Public\Media\WindowsMedia\WindowsVideoTextureOutput.cpp:1761)
11  UnityPlayer                        0x0000000000cbff8e  (C:\build\output\unity\unity\Runtime\Containers\basic_ringbuffer.inl.h:105)
12  UnityPlayer                        0x0000000000cbff8e  (C:\build\output\unity\unity\Runtime\Containers\queue_ringbuffer.inl.h:198)
13  UnityPlayer                        0x0000000000cbff8e  (C:\build\output\unity\unity\Modules\Video\Public\Media\WindowsMedia\WindowsVideoTextureOutput.cpp:1674)
14  UnityPlayer                        0x00007ffb7ca3ff8e WindowsVideoMedia::GetFirstReadyTextureTime (C:\build\output\unity\unity\Modules\Video\Public\Media\WindowsMedia\WindowsVideoMedia.cpp:3278)
15  UnityPlayer                        0x00007ffb7ccea816 VideoMediaTextureOutput::ConsumeFrame (C:\build\output\unity\unity\Modules\Video\Public\Base\VideoMediaOutput.cpp:1206)
16  UnityPlayer                        0x00007ffb7ca304a2 VideoClipPlayback::GetTextureAtTimeInternal (C:\build\output\unity\unity\Modules\Video\Public\Base\VideoMediaPlayback.cpp:1724)
17  UnityPlayer                        0x00007ffb7ca34f91 VideoPlayback::GetTexture (C:\build\output\unity\unity\Modules\Video\Public\Base\MediaComponent.cpp:316)
18  UnityPlayer                        0x00007ffb7ca2d61b VideoPlayer::VideoUpdate (C:\build\output\unity\unity\Modules\Video\Public\VideoPlayer.cpp:1730)
19  UnityPlayer                        0x00007ffb7ca2d4fd VideoManager::VideoUpdate (C:\build\output\unity\unity\Modules\Video\Public\VideoManager.cpp:370)
20  UnityPlayer                        0x00007ffb7c21e1aa ExecutePlayerLoop (C:\build\output\unity\unity\Runtime\Misc\PlayerLoop.cpp:384)
21  UnityPlayer                        0x00007ffb7c21e250 ExecutePlayerLoop (C:\build\output\unity\unity\Runtime\Misc\PlayerLoop.cpp:408)
22  UnityPlayer                        0x00007ffb7c220b78 PlayerLoop (C:\build\output\unity\unity\Runtime\Misc\PlayerLoop.cpp:514)
23  UnityPlayer                        0x00007ffb7c41c09a PerformMainLoop (C:\build\output\unity\unity\PlatformDependent\WinPlayer\WinMain.cpp:329)
24  UnityPlayer                        0x00007ffb7c41adcb MainMessageLoop (C:\build\output\unity\unity\PlatformDependent\WinPlayer\WinMain.cpp:1260)
25  UnityPlayer                        0x00007ffb7c41f5a7 UnityMainImpl (C:\build\output\unity\unity\PlatformDependent\WinPlayer\WinMain.cpp:1777)
26  UnityPlayer                        0x00007ffb7c42110b UnityMain (C:\build\output\unity\unity\PlatformDependent\WinPlayer\WinMain.cpp:1817)
27  Multiplayer POC                    0x00000000000011d1 invoke_main (d:\agent\_work\63\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl:118)
28  Multiplayer POC                    0x00007ff73e6a11f2 _scrt_common_main_seh (d:\agent\_work\63\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl:288)
29  KERNEL32                           0x00007ffc41b97614 BaseThreadInitThunk 
30  ntdll                              0x00007ffc41de26a1 RtlUserThreadStart 
31  ntdll                              0x00007ffc41de26a1 RtlUserThreadStart 

Thread 1
0   ntdll                              0x00007ffc41e2d144 NtWaitForSingleObject 
1   KERNELBASE                         0x00007ffc3f8f306e WaitForSingleObjectEx 
2   UnityPlayer                        0x0000000001060562 ResolveErrorCode (C:\build\output\unity\unity\External\baselib\builds\Source\WinApi\Baselib_Utilities_WinApi.h:20)
3   UnityPlayer                        0x0000000001060554 Baselib_SystemSemaphore_Acquire (C:\build\output\unity\unity\External\baselib\builds\Source\WinApi\Baselib_SystemSemaphore_WinApi.inl.h:35)
4   UnityPlayer                        0x00007ffb7cde0562 UnityClassic::Baselib_SystemSemaphore_Acquire (C:\build\output\unity\unity\External\baselib\builds\Source\CProxy\Baselib_SystemSemaphore_CProxy.inl.h:19)
5   UnityPlayer                        0x00000000004a1017  (C:\build\output\unity\unity\Runtime\Misc\GarbageCollectSharedAssets.cpp:255)
6   UnityPlayer                        0x00007ffb7c221017 AGCThread::RunThread (C:\build\output\unity\unity\Runtime\Misc\GarbageCollectSharedAssets.cpp:231)
7   UnityPlayer                        0x00007ffb7c2f2351 Thread::RunThreadWrapper (C:\build\output\unity\unity\Runtime\Threads\Thread.cpp:82)
8   KERNEL32                           0x00007ffc41b97614 BaseThreadInitThunk 
9   ntdll                              0x00007ffc41de26a1 RtlUserThreadStart 
10  ntdll                              0x00007ffc41de26a1 RtlUserThreadStart 

Thread 2
0   ntdll                              0x00007ffc41e2d144 NtWaitForSingleObject 
1   KERNELBASE                         0x00007ffc3f8f306e WaitForSingleObjectEx 
2   UnityPlayer                        0x0000000001060562 ResolveErrorCode (C:\build\output\unity\unity\External\baselib\builds\Source\WinApi\Baselib_Utilities_WinApi.h:20)
3   UnityPlayer                        0x0000000001060554 Baselib_SystemSemaphore_Acquire (C:\build\output\unity\unity\External\baselib\builds\Source\WinApi\Baselib_SystemSemaphore_WinApi.inl.h:35)
4   UnityPlayer                        0x00007ffb7cde0562 UnityClassic::Baselib_SystemSemaphore_Acquire (C:\build\output\unity\unity\External\baselib\builds\Source\CProxy\Baselib_SystemSemaphore_CProxy.inl.h:19)
5   UnityPlayer                        0x00000000004a1017  (C:\build\output\unity\unity\Runtime\Misc\GarbageCollectSharedAssets.cpp:255)
6   UnityPlayer                        0x00007ffb7c221017 AGCThread::RunThread (C:\build\output\unity\unity\Runtime\Misc\GarbageCollectSharedAssets.cpp:231)
7   UnityPlayer                        0x00007ffb7c2f2351 Thread::RunThreadWrapper (C:\build\output\unity\unity\Runtime\Threads\Thread.cpp:82)
8   KERNEL32                           0x00007ffc41b97614 BaseThreadInitThunk 
9   ntdll                              0x00007ffc41de26a1 RtlUserThreadStart 
10  ntdll                              0x00007ffc41de26a1 RtlUserThreadStart
```

Here is how i am initializing the sdk

```
  void Awake()
    {
        PermissionHelper.RequestMicrophontPermission();
    }
    void Start()
    {
        InitRtcEngine();
        SetBasicConfiguration();
    }

    private void InitRtcEngine()
    {
        agoraEngine = Agora.Rtc.RtcEngine.CreateAgoraRtcEngine();
        AgoraEventHandler handler = new AgoraEventHandler(this);
        RtcEngineContext context = new RtcEngineContext
        (
            appId,
            0,
            CHANNEL_PROFILE_TYPE.CHANNEL_PROFILE_COMMUNICATION,
            AUDIO_SCENARIO_TYPE.AUDIO_SCENARIO_DEFAULT
        );


        agoraEngine.Initialize(context);
        agoraEngine.InitEventHandler(handler);

    }
    private void SetBasicConfiguration()
    {
        agoraEngine.EnableAudio();
        agoraEngine.SetChannelProfile(CHANNEL_PROFILE_TYPE.CHANNEL_PROFILE_COMMUNICATION);
        agoraEngine.SetClientRole(CLIENT_ROLE_TYPE.CLIENT_ROLE_BROADCASTER);
    }
```

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------